# The physics behind Ear Candling

Tags: vacuum

So ear candling is basically putting one end of the hollow candle in the ear and the other end is lit with fire. Now apparently this works because the burning creates a 'vacuum' which causes the earwax to move upwards. However, If this is correct then I don't understand why by burning upwards, the flow of the air goes up[image]

Comment: Ear candling has been shown to [not work](https://www.webmd.com/cold-and-flu/ear-infection/what-is-ear-candling), so I'm not sure if there really is an answer here. Do you have a source that goes over this "physics" in detail? Sources here would help.

Comment: No. The only closest information I could find was on Wikipedia, so I posted this so we can debunk it.

Answer (score 2):

As hot air rises it pulls in air from underneath and around it. This will create a lower pressure in the candle tube and air is pulled into the tube by the rising heated combusted gasses. Whether there are any actual health benefits from ear candling is debatable.

Comment: It does make sense, however, it will produce a very small effect..almost negligible.

Comment: Yes, but a stronger vacuum could do damage, and benefits are uncertain.

Answer (score 0):

Ear candling sounds like Rube Goldberg's replacement for the [Valsalva maneuver - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valsalva_maneuver).

In either method, the air pressure on the inside of the ear drum is temporarily higher than the air pressure on the outside.
The candle induces a slight vacuum externally; the maneuver induces a slight increase in pressure internally.

This can have various effects, some good (e.g. equalizing pressure when in a descending plane flight, or while scuba diving) and some bad (e.g. cardiac arrest or hernia).